# Passing command-line arguments to a Pluto Notebook

Tags: command-line, julia, arguments, pluto.jl

One of the advantages of Pluto is that a notebook `my_notebook.jl` is also a Julia script that can be run using `julia my_notebook.jl`.

In a Julia script, it is easy to set the content of variables using command-line arguments, for instance the following code

```
# example.jl
println("Hello $ARGS[1]")
```

will output `Hello there` when run using `julia example.jl there`.

It turns out that this works as well in a Pluto notebook, but only if you execute it as a script `julia my_notebook.jl there`.

I would like to be able to open the notebook using `julia -e "using Pluto; Pluto.run(notebook=\"example.jl\")" there` and see the result inside the notebook. It turns out this syntax returns an error: I could not find any way to populate the variable `ARGS` inside the Pluto notebook.

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems that there is no such option around the `Pluto.Configuration` module, this can be easily circumvented by using system environment variables which are inherited by the child process.

Consider this Julia session:

```
$ julia -e "" --interactive one two

julia> ARGS
2-element Vector{String}:
 "one"
 "two"

julia> ENV["PLUTO_ARGS"] = join(ARGS,"\n");

julia> using Pluto

julia> Pluto.run()
```

Now in Pluto you can see those parameters in `ENV["PLUTO_ARGS"]`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did not think of this workaround but it works perfectly as intended!
I added the following cell in order to store the command-line arguments in the same variable as a standard julia script, so that I can run the same code as a script or as a notebook.
`if :pluto_boot_environment_path in names(Main)
        try
                ARGS = split(ENV["PLUTO_ARGS"])
        catch
                ARGS = []
        end
end`